# Nodejs - Crypto error - this._handle.update(data, encoding);

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I'm using node v4.8.0 (npm v3.10.10) and in my service code i'm generating a hash using Crypto something like below,

```
hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')
             .update(val1+val2+JSON.stringify(val3), 'utf8')
             .digest('hex');
```

when i build the app it fails with the below error, it was working few weeks back and all of a sudden ended getting the error. Any idea how could i overcome this one, this seems to be a viable solution https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4072 but not getting it fully though since i'm not explicitly using web pack as i'm dealing with an API and not a client app

Error:

```
crypto.js:70
this._handle.update(data, encoding);
^

TypeError: Not a string or buffer
 at TypeError (native)
 at Hash.update (crypto.js:70:16)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/approot/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:14:81)
 at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  ......
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

So I guess one of your data is null or something else than a string or buffer.

Comment: getting this error while just building the app so wondering why does it check those values while the app is building and the above hash is created only in a specific scenario which can be executed after the applications successful deployment. Wondering why it fails during the build phase.